# Is sw480dp supported in API 9?

Tags: android, api, size, screen

I am having errors for placing both the layout-large and layout-sw480dp files.
So is layout-sw480dp supported for API 9 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `-w`, `-h`, and `-sw` series of resource set qualifiers [were added in API Level 13](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) (look for them in "Table 2").

> I am having errors for placing both the layout-large and layout-sw480dp files

You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with the errors that you are getting.

Comment: Oh thanks,but then why am i getting the :'Large Screen' is not a best match for any device/locale combination . error?

Comment: @K-M: I have no idea what "the :'Large Screen'" means, sorry.

Comment: It's reffering to the "layout-large" folder i created to support large screen sizes (480dp).

Comment: @K-M: I do not recall ever seeing a "not a best match" error message in an IDE or during command-line builds. As I wrote in my answer, you may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, and show where you are getting this error. However, there are very few Android devices in use today that would qualify for `-large` that are running less than API Level 15. There is little value in having `layout-large` *and* `layout-sw480dp` as a result, so perhaps that is what is triggering the message that you are seeing.

Comment: Really thanks for the info,and looks your right because after removing the layout-large folder,things are back to normal.